# Android Ripple effect for ImageView "state_select" Not Working

Tags: android, ripple, xml-drawable, rippledrawable

I am developing Ripple effect for ImageView in Lolipop.  My drawable XML is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight"
    tools:targetApi="21">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_unselected"/>
</ripple>
```

And In XML i am giving SRC to ImageView like below.

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_tab_item" />
```

My problem is in Activity.java, if i mention

```
ImageView.setSelected(true);
```

It is not showing selected image.

Please help me where i am doing wrong.